# SQL Full join on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, join

I'm trying to join two tables but the columns emp_id and scheme_id may be null or not populated in either table but if it is populated in either then I need to return the total pen_ee for that employee for each scheme (further table descriptions below). I can't edit the table structure and have to work with what I have.

I've been trying to use a full join to do this but don't understand if you can do a full join on two fields emp_id & scheme_id to get the required result.

**Table PAYAUDPEN**
This is the first two months of the year.
 
 - Employee A has given 44.06 to scheme BMAL.
 - Employee B has given 98.06 to scheme BMAL.
 - Employee B has given 98.06 to scheme CLFL.

```
emp_id, period_id, scheme_id, pen_ee
A,      201601,         BMAL, 22.03
A,      201602,         BMAL, 22.03
B,      201601,         BMAL, 98.06
B,      201602,         CLFL, 98.06
```

**Table PAYISPEN**
This is the third & current month of the year. The system always puts the current month into this table)
- Employee A gave 22.03.
- Employee B gave 98.06.
 (Note employee B did not contribute to the BMAL scheme again in month 3 which is part of the issue).

```
emp_id, scheme_id, pen_ee
A, BMAL, 22.03
B, CLFL, 98.06
```

**Required Result**
The SQL statement needs to return the 3 periods added together, for each employee for each scheme that they contributed to.
- Employee A would be 44.06 + 22.03=66.09  for scheme BMAL.
- Employee B would be 98.06 + NULL =98.06  for scheme BMAL.
- Employee B would be 98.06 + 98.06=196.12 for scheme CLFL.

```
A, BMAL, 66.09  
B, BMAL, 98.06
B, CLFL, 196.12
```

To create the basics of the two tables and populate with the example data above run the following queries.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payaudpen](
[emp_id] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[period_id] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[scheme_id] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[pen_ee] [numeric](15, 2) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payispen](
[emp_id] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[scheme_id] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[pen_ee] [numeric](15, 2) NULL )

INSERT INTO payaudpen VALUES ('A','201601','BMAL','22.03'), ('A','201602','BMAL','22.03'), ('B','201601','BMAL','98.06'), ('B','201602','CLFL','98.06')
INSERT INTO payispen VALUES ('A','BMAL','22.03'), ('B','CLFL','98.06')
```

Current statement that I'm using:

```
SELECT a.emp_id,
       a.scheme_id,
       SUM(a.pen_ee)+AVG(b.pen_ee)
FROM payaudpen a 
FULL JOIN payispen b 
  ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
GROUP BY a.scheme_id, a.emp_id
```

**Incorrect result**
Doesn't return the correct value for employee B for each scheme.

```
A, BMAL, 66.09  
B, BMAL, 196.12
B, CLFL, 196.12
```

Comment: A value of "C" mysteriously appears in the desired results but is not in any of the input columns.

Comment: I was reading the question and thinking the same! Where did it came from? the 'C' value

Comment: I think OP meant to imply "..." at the end of the example tables.

Comment: If, as you say, "the columns emp_id and scheme_id may or may not exist in either table", then you can't safely use either column in your `ON` clause. Did you mean, instead, that those may have `NULL` values?

Comment: By "the columns emp_id and scheme_id may or may not exist " I presume you mean that these columns may or may not contain `NULL` in any given row.  If the columns themselves actually might not *exist* then you cannot perform your join at all.

Comment: Or do you just mean that *values* of `emp_id` and `scheme_id` from one table may not correspond to values of the same-named columns in any row of the other table?

Comment: Sorry updated the C to be a B.

Comment: With the latest version of your example data, where is a row for `B`, `BMAL` supposed to come from, and why isn't there one for `A`, `CLFL`?

Comment: Can you see B now in the table Payaudpen now?

Comment: The where clause destroys the full join. `a.emp_id in ('A', 'B')` will filter out all rows were a.emp_id is null, including rows created by the full join. Ditto `period_id in (...)` for which ever table perdiod_id is in. Depending on what you want, it may work to move those criteria to the on clause.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I agree that the where clause would destroy the full join but as emp_id exists in both tables in the example data above I don't think it would matter currently. When ran on the full table I would be removing this where clause

Comment: Create table statements and inserts for sample data would be nice. Sounds like you may want something like `SELECT a.emp_id, a.scheme_id, SUM(a.pen_ee)+AVG(b.pen_ee) FROM payaudpen a INNER JOIN payispen b ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id or a.scheme_id = b.scheme_id WHERE a.emp_id in ('A','B') and period_id in ('201601','201602') GROUP BY a.scheme_id, a.emp_id` But then the SUM might over count. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Never thought of create table statements as I wasn't sure how best to get it on here, might take a bit of time and do that. The above example is just small simplified sample of a much larger table.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance tried your query there but as you feared the OR resulted in the rows being returned too many times so the SUM is high. It's difficult to explain but if you concatenate emp_id & scheme_id in both tables and then did a full join on them that is effectively what I'm trying to get.

Comment: I know every one is trying to get the OPs query to work. But shouldn't we stop and see what is wrong here. The result he is looking for does not make sense in terms of what the current dataset is. @CantGetItToWork unless you think I am mistaken?  Based on the logic for A, BMAL 66.09 you would expect to see 2 B, CLFL 196.12 as well as 1 B, BMAL 98.06.

Comment: @TYY logic explained for how employee B can contribute to scheme BMAL and then CLFL in a future month if they switch.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I've now created sql's for the table creation & sample data if you would like to run these & have another look. Lots of extra details added as well to the initial descriptions in the hope that it makes it more clear.

Comment: Why is "Employee B would be 0.00 + 98.06=98.06 for scheme CLFL." When (B,CLFL) exists in both tables with an amount of 98.06?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance you are correct, this should have read "Employee B would be 98.06 + 98.06 = 196.12 for scheme CLFL" as CLFL was in both tables for this employee. Apologies, I think I have been staring at this too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to sum across two tables, use union all to make the tables into one relation with more rows, instead of join to make the tables into a relation with more columns:

```
WITH all_records AS (SELECT emp_id
            , scheme_id
            , pen_ee 
        FROM payispen
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT emp_id
        , scheme_id
        , pen_ee FROM payaudpen)
SELECT emp_id, scheme_id, SUM(pen_ee)
FROM all_records    
GROUP BY emp_id, scheme_id
```

Results:

```
emp_id  scheme_id   (No column name)
A           BMAL        66.09
B           BMAL        98.06
B           CLFL        196.12
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with WITH statements but I've been testing it on the larger data tables that I have & it seems to work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to join only rows that have both the same `emp_id` *and* the same `scheme_id`.  This is possible in outer joins, just as it is in inner joins.  I infer that you also want to merge the `emp_id` and `scheme_id` columns from the two tables so that when `a` does not provide them, they come from `b`, instead.  This will do it:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(a.emp_id, b.emp_id) AS emp_id,
  COALESCE(a.scheme_id, b.scheme_id) AS scheme_id,
  SUM(a.pen_ee)+AVG(b.pen_ee) AS pen_ee
FROM
  payaudpen a 
  FULL JOIN payispen b 
    ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.scheme_id = b.scheme_id
WHERE
  COALESCE(a.emp_id, b.emp_id) in ('A','B') 
    AND (a.period_id IS NULL OR a.period_id in ('201601','201602'))
GROUP BY COALESCE(a.scheme_id, b.scheme_id), COALESCE(a.emp_id, b.emp_id)
```

Note the use of `COALESCE()` to handle the cases where table `a` does not provide `emp_id` or `scheme_id`; with SQL Server you could also use `ISNULL()` in its place.  Note also the allowance for `a.period_id IS NULL` in the `WHERE` condition -- this is necessary (in conjunction with the `COALESCE()`ing) to include data from `b` rows that do not have corresponding `a` rows.

Comment: @ConradFrix, no, that would have a different meaning.  Rows of table `a` not satisfying the condition would still be included in the result (because it's a (full) *outer* join); they just would not be joined to any `b` rows.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hi John tried that statement & got A, BMAL, 66.09, B, BMAL, NULL, C, CLFL, 196.12. I'm trying to get A, BMAL, 66.09, B, BMAL, 98.06, C, CLFL, 98.06

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you need to change in your solution is to use ISNULL() to make sure the key appears when table b has data but not table a. Otherwise, you'll get rows which look like:

NULL   |    NULL   |    98.06

I recommend:

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.emp_id,b.emp_id) AS emp_id
       ISNULL(a.scheme_id, b.scheme_id) AS scheme_id
       SUM(a.pen_ee)+AVG(b.pen_ee) AS pen_ee
FROM payaudpen a 
FULL JOIN payispen b 
  ON a.emp_id=b.emp_id
  AND a.scheme_id=b.scheme_id
WHERE a.emp_id in ('A','B') 
      and period_id in ('201601','201602')
GROUP BY ISNULL(a.emp_id,b.emp_id), ISNULL(a.scheme_id, b.scheme_id)
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution above but It doesn't seem quite right. The returned output was A, BMAL, 66.09, B, BMAL, 196.12, B, CLFL, 196.12

Comment: I have made a change to the ON clause. Does it work now?

Comment: No luck, I've added a lot more detail to my initial post if you want to have another look. The returned output this time was A, BMAL, 66.09, B, BMAL, NULL, B, CLFL, 196.12.

Comment: You'll need to wrap the `sum` and `avg` in `isnull(..,0)` in the case of nothing but nulls from the other side of the join.

Comment: This solution also seems to work as I have been testing it yesterday and haven't found any problems with it on the larger data sets. Thanks!